# Constexpr destructor of a class with union field containing not-trivial type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, unions

In the following program not-literal struct `A` is used inside of `union` field of another class defining `constexpr` destructor:

```
struct A { 
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};

struct S {
  union {
    int i;
    A a;
  };
  enum { ti, ta } type;

  constexpr S() : i(1), type(ti) {}
  constexpr ~S() {
      if ( type == ta ) a.~A();
  }
};

static_assert( S{}.i == 1 );
```

GCC permits this code, but Clang emits the error:

```
error: destructor cannot be declared constexpr because data member '' does not have a constexpr destructor
```

MSVC also rejects it:

```
error C3615: constexpr function 'S::~S' cannot result in a constant expression
note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
note: see usage of 'A::~A'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qKW45fdE6

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Making the destructor of `A` `constexpr` allows MSVC to compile it, and additionally making the constructor of `A` `constexpr` allows Clang to compile it as well, so I guess it comes down to whether the SMFs of `A` should be implicitly `constexpr`.